# Dice game in Python: randint and victory message

Tags: python, random, dice

I'm experimenting a bit and trying to make a simple dice game.
I want it to be so one could guess a number between 1-6, then have a dice randomly generate a number, and giving a message depending on if one was right or not.

I have tried:

```
guess_1 = input("Guess the number on the dice: ")
print("You have entered " + guess_1)

from random import randint
dice = randint(1,6)

if guess_1 == dice:
    print(f"The result was {dice}. Congratulations, you win!")
else:
    print(f"The result was {dice}. Sorry, try again!")
```

However, now, even if I guess correctly, I still wind up with
"You have entered 6
The result was 6. Sorry, try again!"

Does anyone know what I have done wrong here?
And if there is a way to do so that you get an error message if you write e.g. 15 instead of a number within the range of the dice?

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `input` returns a string (such as "1", "2", etc.).  This needs to be converted to an integer.  Try: `guess_1 = int(input("Guess the number on the dice: "))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing between a string and an integer(when you use "input()", the default data type is string.) You need to convert your input to an integer first, and then compare.

```
from random import randint
guess_1 = int(input("Guess the number on the dice: "))
print("You have entered " + guess_1)

dice = randint(1,6)

if guess_1 == dice:
    print(f"The result was {dice}. Congratulations, you win!")
else:
    print(f"The result was {dice}. Sorry, try again!")
```

Answer (score 1):

This can help:

```
from random import randint

guess_1 = int(input("Guess the number on the dice: "))
print(f"You have entered: {guess_1}")

dice = randint(1,6)

if guess_1 == dice:
    print(f"The result was {dice}. Congratulations, you win!")
else:
    print(f"The result was {dice}. Sorry, try again!")
```